# Swing extend JTextField with margin

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to set a margin to my JTextField,

therefore I did:

```
class MyJTextField extends JTextField {

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    System.err.println("paint " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 25));
    super.paint(g);
}
}
```

I mean it works, but I would expect paint to be called in an endless loop because the JavaDoc of setMargin says: "... This causes a redraw of the component". Why am I wrong?

Comment: Why in paint? Why not in constructor?

Comment: The margin can change during runtime (simplified the example)

Comment: You should adopt a "push" model: call setMargin() from an event handler for an event that requires recomputation of the margin, relying on automatic layout invalidation and update. The paint() method should paint the component, without changing it; it is a completely inappropriate context for figuring out the appropriate margin size.

Answer (score 0):

This will cause redraw only at once. Each next setMargin do nothing because the class Insets has a custom method equals. When you set the same object twice no property change occured and no redraw called.

Comment: but it calls invalidate on the component ?! Doesn't this lead to a repaint?

Comment: I assert that the layout manager is smart, and can also determine that nothing is changed and no repainting required. But you are right, it's a little bit mysterious.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for border.

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1);
textField.setBorder(border);
```